# panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter

Tags: go, concurrency

My goal is to use goroutines and channel, i want to learn how to communicate between different goroutines and i want to avoid deadlock. I managed to use `sync.WaitGroup` and it is working just fine.

However I received an error saying that

> 1 panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter
>
> goroutine 19 [running]:

**The goal of this program is simple.**

1. Create a developer
2. Assign him/her to create a website
3. Depends on the number of the websites
4. Once website is done then append it to the array
5. Let there are 20 websites and 5 developers
6. Each developer will take create 4 websites and append it to the websites array
7. I want to do it concurrently so that other developers don't have to wait

**The code:**

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sync"
  "time"
)

type developer struct {
    name              string
    setTimeForWebsite time.Time
}

type website struct {
   owner   string
   created time.Time
}

var developers []developer
var websites []website

// A function to create a developer
 func hireDeveloper(wg *sync.WaitGroup, workNumber int, 
   developerCreatedc chan developer, devs []developer) {
   defer wg.Done()
   developerNumber := fmt.Sprintf("developer_%d", workNumber)
   d := developer{name: developerNumber}
   fmt.Println("Hired", d.name)
   developerCreatedc <- d
 }

 // A function to create a website
  func createComputer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, developerCreatedc chan developer, websitePerComputer int, websites []website) {
  defer wg.Done()
   // Assign the developer to the website creation // N number of the website
  d := <-developerCreatedc
  for i := 0; i <= websitePerComputer; i++ {
    fmt.Println("Delegate", d.name, "to set the time to start 
    building the website")
    d.setTimeForWebsite = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(d.name, "Finish calculating to build the website", d.setTimeForWebsite)
    web := website{owner: d.name, created: d.setTimeForWebsite}
    websites = append(websites, web)
    fmt.Println(len(websites))
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println(d.name, "Created website at", web.created)
   }

  }

func main() {

  // Make a channel for when developer is hired 
  developerCreatedC := make(chan developer)
  // create a sync group
  wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
  // Assume that number of websites are 20
  numberOfWebsites := 20
  // Assume that number of developers are 5
  numberOfDevelopers := 5
  // Divide the websites to 5 developers
  websitePerDeveloper := numberOfWebsites / numberOfDevelopers
  // add the sync
  wg.Add(1)
  for i := 1; i <= numberOfDevelopers; i++ {
    go func(producerNumber int) {
        hireDeveloper(wg, producerNumber, developerCreatedC, 
        developers)
    }(i)
   }

  wg.Add(1)
  for i := 1; i <= websitePerDeveloper; i++ {
    createComputer(wg, developerCreatedC, 5, websites)
  }

  wg.Wait()
}
```

The playground
https://play.golang.org/p/QSOv5jp3T94

The behaviour is a bit sometimes, one developer created more than 4 websites, even though it is supposed to create only 4

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wg.Add()` should be equal to the number number of go routine you are running. Also `createComputer(wg, developerCreatedC, websitePerDeveloper, websites)` should be per developer basis.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type developer struct {
    name              string
    setTimeForWebsite time.Time
}

type website struct {
    owner   string
    created time.Time
}

var developers []developer
var websites []website

// A function to create a developer
func hireDeveloper(wg *sync.WaitGroup, workNumber int, developerCreatedc chan developer, devs []developer) {
    defer wg.Done()
    developerNumber := fmt.Sprintf("developer_%d", workNumber)
    d := developer{name: developerNumber}
    fmt.Println("Hired", d.name)
    developerCreatedc <- d
}

// A function to create a website
func createComputer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, developerCreatedc chan developer, websitePerComputer int, websites []website) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // Assign the developer to the website creation // N number of the website
    d := <-developerCreatedc
    for i := 0; i <= websitePerComputer; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Delegate", d.name, "to set the time to start building the website")
        d.setTimeForWebsite = time.Now()
        web := website{owner: d.name, created: d.setTimeForWebsite}
        websites = append(websites, web)
        fmt.Println(len(websites))
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        fmt.Println(d.name, "Created website at", web.created)
    }

}

func main() {

    // Make a channel for when developer is hired 
    developerCreatedC := make(chan developer)
    // create a sync group
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    // Assume that number of websites are 20
    numberOfWebsites := 20
    // Assume that number of developers are 5
    numberOfDevelopers := 5
    // Divide the websites to 5 developers
    websitePerDeveloper := numberOfWebsites / numberOfDevelopers

    for i := 1; i <= numberOfDevelopers; i++ {
        // add the sync
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(producerNumber int) {
            hireDeveloper(wg, producerNumber, developerCreatedC, developers)
        }(i)

        wg.Add(1)
        go createComputer(wg, developerCreatedC, websitePerDeveloper, websites)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive the error because you do `wg.Add(1)` before the loop.
Every call to `hireDeveloper()` and `createComputer()` calls `wg.Done()`, so already in the first for loop `wg` wants to count down till -4 which is not possible thus the panic.

A possible solution would be:

```
wg.Add(numberOfDevelopers)
for i := 1; i <= numberOfDevelopers; i++ {...}
....
wg.Add(websitePerDeveloper)
for i := 1; i <= websitePerDeveloper; i++ {...}
```

or you pull wg.Add into the for loop:

```
      for i := 1; i <= numberOfDevelopers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(producerNumber int) {
            hireDeveloper(wg, producerNumber, developerCreatedC, 
            developers)
        }(i)
   }
```

Comment: I receive ```fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!```

Comment: The reason probably lays in your channels. Now it correctly blocks at wg.wait and your main go routine waits for ever instead of exiting early.
I will update the answer in case I find something.

Comment: @sinusGob so you receive a deadlock because you call 'createComputer' 20 times. In  'createComputer' you ask for a Developer (20 times because you called it 20x) but you only created 5. As ' d := <-developerCreatedc' is a blocking action you end up in a deadlock because this line waits for input